# jQuery ui modal window causes gray line

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I wanted to change the color of the window surrounding the modal alert-popup in jQuery UI. 
So I changed it; `.ui-widget-overlay { background: white` 
But for some weird reason, a gray line with the previously existing color, shows up in the middle of the screen. I haven't been able to select the element with the Chrome debugger, nor have I been able to find it's class in the jQuery-ui css-file. See image.

Anyone know what could be causing this?

[image]

Comment: If you restore the CSS to the way it was, and then pass the `overlay.background` option, does the problem persist?

Comment: Do you mean something like this? http://forum.jquery.com/topic/jquery-ui-dialog-documentation-is-missing-overlay-option
I tried that but it didn't work for me, the background color didn't change at all.

Comment: The widget can take an option, `overlay`, which is an object of css style property names/values. It is not in the docs, though, and per the thread you linked it was removed from the docs in favor of modifying the CSS in the manner in which you describe in your post. So I guess that's no help.

Comment: what version of jQuery and jQuery UI are you using? The latest ones in jsfiddle seems to work fine: http://jsfiddle.net/william/UMMap/.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed this. For some reason, my jquery-ui.css file had two .ui-widget-overlay classes defined. Added the background-color as in Williams example to the other class and it worked.